# Spring WebFlow flow-registry URL Mapping

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Is there a way to write a spring webflow flow-registry to match on a pathname, and then also all urls under it as well?

For instance, I can match on /myService with the following:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="builder">
  <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/myService-webflow.xml" id="myService"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

But I don't know how to get it to also match on /myService/*

Comment: how did you define urlHandlerMapping - show the configuration?

Comment: I don't think a urlHandlerMapping is applicable here. Configuration also shouldn't be of interest because, (as far as I know) a flow-registry behaves in a similar manner regardless of the rest of the config. I've added a simple flow-registry and re-worded the question to help better explain what I want to do.